# Recreating a list with values from an updated database

Tags: c#, mysql, list

I would like to recreate my list after it is updated (at `allocate positions`) so that it includes the new columns in the position table. Is this possible? How would I go about doing it?

I've tried clearing it and attempting to read the dataReader again, but with little success, will I have to rerun the SQL query?

```
    public List<BidList> AllocateBids()
    {
        // Determine positions
        string query =
            "SELECT t1.operator_id, t1.datetime, t1.plot_id, t1.position, t2.market_access FROM bid t1 " +
            "JOIN operator t2 ON t1.operator_id = t2.id WHERE t1.status='Queued' AND t1.postcode='" + _plot + "'" +
            "ORDER BY t2.market_access ASC, t1.datetime ASC";
        var bidList = new List<BidList>();
        var cmd = new MySqlCommand(query, _connection);
        MySqlDataReader dataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (dataReader.Read())
        {
            var item = new BidList
            {
                OperatorId = dataReader["operator_id"] + "",
                PlotId = dataReader["plot_id"] + "", 
                Position = dataReader["position"] + "",
                Datetime = dataReader["datetime"] + "",
                MarketAccess = dataReader["market_access"] + "",
            };
            bidList.Add(item);
        }

        // Allocate positions 
        for (var i = 0; i < bidList.Count; i++)
        {
            var position = i + 1;
            query = "UPDATE bid SET position='" + position + "' WHERE operator_id='" + bidList[i].OperatorId +
                        "'";
            var dbObject = new DbConnect();
            dbObject.InsertBooking(query);
        }

        return bidList;

        // Recreate list
        //bidList.Clear();
        //while (dataReader.Read())
        //{
        //    var item = new BidList
        //    {
        //        OperatorId = dataReader["operator_id"] + "",
        //        PlotId = dataReader["plot_id"] + "",
        //        Position = dataReader["position"] + "",
        //        Datetime = dataReader["datetime"] + "",
        //        MarketAccess = dataReader["market_access"] + "",
        //    };
        //    bidList.Add(item);
        //}

        //CloseConnection();
        //return bidList;
    }
```

Comment: you're updating the list right after getting them from the database and want to return it in the order you set the position?

Comment: Yes - in a nutshell. You will notice that the same database I create the list from is updated in `allocate positions`. I would like to now recreate the list with the updated values in the position field.

Comment: As a side note: you should really use SqlParameters not plain string queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instead of recreate the list, if you're updating only 1 field, and it's the position one, why don't you reorder it like this:

```
// Allocate positions 
    for (var i = 0; i < bidList.Count; i++)
    {
        var position = i + 1;

        bidList[i].Position = position;

        query = "UPDATE bid SET position='" + position + "' WHERE operator_id='" + bidList[i].OperatorId +
                    "'";
        var dbObject = new DbConnect();
        dbObject.InsertBooking(query);
    }

    return bidList.OrderBy(bid => bid.Position);
```

bidList.OrderBy() will return the same List, ordered by the position values you just assigned it